# Магический метод __call() PHP

Tags: php

С помощью магического метода call передаю в функцию параметры в виде массива:

```
$response = $this->get(array("shop" => $shop, "resource" => $resource, "update" => NULL));
```

Причём `$shop` - обьект, `$resource` - массив. 
Как потом достучаться до этих значений ключей? 
На `$arguments["shop"]` - пишет `undefined index`.

Comment: в смысле передаете с помощью __call ? магический метод __call вызывается если вы обращаетесь к методу объекта которого не существует

Comment: да, так и есть. Но в этот call я хочу аргументом передать массив

Comment: Ассоциативный, у которого ключи принимают выше сказанные значения

Comment: Вы откройте руководство, там увидите что в `__call` вторым аргументом передается __массив__ параметров. Соответственно если у вас параметр - массив, то получается уже массив в массиве.

Comment: Как @u_mulder и написал, вам надо стучаться в 0 эл-т массива аргумментов.. `$arguments[0]["shop"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так называемый [магический метод `__call`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) требует быть объявленным с двумя аргументами:

1. строкой имени вызываемого метода
2. массивом переданных методу аргументов

Массив аргументов передаётся в виде числового массива, в порядке указанных в вызове метода аргументов.

```
class A
{
    public function __call($method, array $args)
    {
        var_dump($method, $args);
    }
}

$a = new A;
$a->get(array(1,2,3));
```

Так, если вы хотите обратиться к первому параметру вызванного метода `get` - вам нужен `$args[0]`.

Comment: А если мы к примеру передаем ассоциативный массив, с ключем `"shop" => $shop` например, то обращаться нужно `$args[0]["shop"]`?

Comment: Может можно попробовать и проверить самостоятельно?